# How stop scrolling on google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I wrote the code to stop scrolling on map in android. But overlay add when MotionEvent.ACTION_UP happen. How i fix it? or how i stop map scrolling?

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

  if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon16);

                    // create and add an OverlayItem to the MyItemizedOverlay list
                    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(gPt, "", "");

                    itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable,context);
                    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

                    // add the overlays to the map
                    mMapVw.getOverlays().clear();
                    mMapVw.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);


                  return true;



            }
        }


        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setClickable(false);` should disable all touch events to the MapView.

Comment: But at that time no moving occur for example i can't move overlay on the map